An error occurred while installing rdkafka (0.6.0.pre.c16), and Bundler cannot continue
After getting latest coupa_develoment branch and running bundle install, I received the following error message:
RdKafka.cpp:29:10: fatal error: ‘string’ file not found
29 | #include 
|          ^~~~~~~~
I am using MacBook Pro, MacOs Sonoma 14.7, Intel
xcode-select -p command showed that I was using /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
Downloading XCode and switching to it (sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer) fixed the problem.
